# Visual Studio addin; to highlight all words which match selected word?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-addins

While using NotePad++, and select a certain word, it automatically highlights all matched words?

[image]

Does anyone know if there is a Visual Studio addin that can do this? or are there any hidden environment setting that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that is automatically done by VS 2010 though if you are using an older version of VS you can get that functionality with third-party addins. For example I used to use an add-in called RockScroll that could highlight usages in a source file (By double clicking on the word) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx.

Also ReSharper has that functionality built into it with Cntl + Shft + F7

Answer (score 7):

Check following addins
[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) addin 
The background colour of the highlight in Productivity Power Tools is found under 
Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools->Enhanced Scroll Bar->Words Matching The Caret Location Color In The Editor.

or

Use [Highlight selected word](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb/) addin.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) can do that.  This can be switched on in Settings -> Refactoring -> Automatically highlight references to symbol under cursor.

[image]

Comment: Upon this http://www.wholetomato.com/products/featureColor.asp, highlight selected word is not listed in their Enhanced Syntax Coloring, or am I missing it?

Comment: See edit.  It does exist.  But it only works for C++ symbols and keywords, not for just any words.

Comment: There is a separate feature for plain text.  It is described here: http://blog.wholetomato.com/2009/01/06/mark-all-occurrences-va-x-105/ and the documentation page is here: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/highlightFindResults.asp